# Unable to increase the counter to the Badge in React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am not sure where to apply the count to my Badge Component. The displayValue should have the count but I am not sure how to apply it.

**EDITED :**
Counter is applied now but when I decrement the counter , after 0 , it should disappear. I have the logic for this and it works only when I apply badgeContent ="0" in App.tsx and not when the badge is 0 by clicking the decrement button.

I tried it on codesandbox. Here is the link. Please help. Thanks!

https://codesandbox.io/s/badgecomponent-ljdq25?file=/src/components/Badge.tsx:468-480

Comment: Please fix your link, it points to stack overflow

Comment: You just need to use count in your displayValue calculation:
`let displayValue =
  count && count > max ? `${max}+` : String(count);
`
I also converted it to a string, since you're displaying it as text.
Number(badgeContent) > 0 is an anti-pattern. Just use badgeContent > 0, since badgeContent is already a number due to type checking. Parsing it to a number again is redundant.

Comment: Thanks! I also added the decrement logic. Please review it, When the Badge has a decrement value of 0 ,  it's still shows 0. I have logic for it to disappear when it is 0 but it doesn't work from the button but works when I have badgeContent="0" in App.tsx. Can you please check and let me know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see `badgeContent` is string so I added it to the state and converted it to the number `const [count, setCount] = useState(+badgeContent);`

and controlling `count` in the event listener as:

```
  const incrementBadge = () => {
    console.log("Badge Clicked");
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
```

A dedicated function for getting the badgeText:

```
  const getBadeText = () =>
    if (count === 0 && !showZero) return undefined;
    else if (count > max) return `${max}+`;
    return count;
  }
```

And showing the badge in UI as:

```
  <span className="badge">
    <span className={`badgeText`}>Badge</span>
    {getBadgeText() !== undefined ? <span className={`badgeContent`}>{getBadgeText()}</span> : ""}
  </span>
```

Please check out the full codes on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/badgecomponent-forked-sdxmoj?file=/src/components/Badge.tsx)

Comment: Thanks! This works but now when the max > 99 then the badge should be 99+ and that logic is not working after we apply the count. How can we fix it?

Comment: then do something like this `        {count > 0 && count <= max ? (
          <span className={`badgeContent`}>{count}</span>
        ) : (
          <span className={`badgeContent`}>{`99+`}</span>
        )}`

I have also adapted the Sandbox codes: https://codesandbox.io/s/badgecomponent-forked-sdxmoj?file=/src/components/Badge.tsx

Comment: so you don't need this 
`if (count < max) { setCount(count + 1);}` just use `setCount(count + 1);`

Comment: No this doesn't work. If you look at my code sandbox now, I have everything working except when the counter is 0 by pressing the decrement button the badge should disappear. I can make that happen from App.tsx but not with the button.

Comment: I have adapted to your new requirement please checkout the codesandbox as well.

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm :) . I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your count is incrementing, but it's not wired up to anything. If you change your code to use `count` your state will update. So change

```
{Number(badgeContent) > 0 && (
   <span className={`badgeContent`}>{displayValue}</span>
)}
```

to:

```
{Number(badgeContent) > 0 && (
   <span className={`badgeContent`}>{count}</span>
)}
```